# Copy Files from Host to Image with Docker

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2017

I have a .NET Core Console app that I am trying to host within a Docker image. The default Dockerfile will not work for me because VSTS cannot run the Dockerfile AND retrieve NuGet packages from a private repo. For that reason, I'm looking to compile my project first. Then, copy the files from the ./bin/Release directory into the Docker image. However, at this time, I'm receiving the error message:

```
failed to build: COPY failed: no source files were specified
```

The directory of my solution and project look like this:

```
MySolution
  MyProject
    bin
      Release
        netcoreapp2.1
    Dockerfile
    Program.cs
    MyProject.csproj    
  .dockerignore
  docker-compose.dcproj
  docker-compose.override.yml
  docker-compose.yml
  MySolution.sln
  README.md
```

My Dockerfile looks like this:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
ENV myVariable 12345
COPY ./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/* /app
```

I don't understand why I'm getting the error `no source files were specified`. I can see them in the `bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1` directory. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
COPY ./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/* /app
```

with

```
COPY ./bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/. /app/
```

Comment: When I try that I receive the following error: `COPY failed: CreateFile \\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\docker-builder029641602\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1: The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: @ZachTempleton I just double checked this. the problem is not with COPY command, it works here, unless you provide more context I can't help you.

Comment: @ZachTempleton I just double checked this. the problem is not with COPY command, it works here, unless you provide more context I can't help you.